# "Cannot assign to var because it is a read-only property." in angular test using Jasmine Test Framework

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have a readonly property in one of the service in angular :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class MyService {
  private readonly timeIntervals: any;
}

constructor(private readonly config: AppConfig) {
    this.timeIntervals = this.config.getResourceByKey(this.timeIntervalString);
}



getTimeIntervalMenuItem(): Array<IElementData>{
    const menuListItems = new Array<IElementData>();
    let index = 0;
    for (const item of Object.keys(this.timeIntervals)) {
      menuListItems.push({
        id: this.menuItem + index.toString(),
        label: this.timeIntervals[item].toString()
      });
      index++;
    }
    return menuListItems;
  }

export interface IElementData {
    label?: string;
    value?: string;
    id?: string;
    active?: string;
}
```

While writing test for the same service, how will I assign value to timeIntervals?

What I did was:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MyService,
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(MyService);
  });

it('should generate total 7 menu items for dropdown', () => {
    const timeIntervals = 'timeIntervals';
    service[timeIntervals] = timeLists;
    const generatedMenu = service.getTimeIntervalMenuItem();
    expect(generatedMenu.length).toBe(7);
  });

const timeLists = {
  3: '3',
  5: '5',
  10: '10',
  15: '15',
  20: '20',
  30: '30',
  60: '60'
};
```

I am getting error as:

> Cannot assign to 'timeIntervals' because it is a read-only property.

How to assign value to timeIntervals so that I can test my method

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured out solution by using

> Object.defineProperty

Code:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MyService
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.get(MyService);
    const timeIntervals = 'timeIntervals';
    Object.defineProperty(service, timeIntervals, { value: timeLists });
  });
```

Comment: How do you then use it in an 'expect' context? How do you replace your previous generatedMenu variable?

Answer (score 8):

You can use

> JavaScript : Object Writable attribute, for more informations please refer to : [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/defineProperty)

```
Object.defineProperty(service, timeIntervals, { writable: true});
```

if you want to see a descirption of your properties [you can use](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)

> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()