# Angular 9 - router.url readonly property within TestBed RouterTestingModule

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular9

I'm upgrading from Angular 8 to Angular 10 incrementally.  When hitting version 9, all of my `TestBed.get(Router).url` calls errored due to it now being a readonly property.

For example:  `TestBed.get(Router).url = '/map';` no longer works.

I have tried some `spyOn` options and additionally tried providing my path within the `RouterTestingModule` itself, but these ultimately didn't work or didn't serve my needs with multiple routes.

Example of path provision in RouterTestingModule:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    {
       provide: Router,
       useValue: {
          url: '/path'
       } // you could use also jasmine.createSpyObj() for methods
    } 
  ]
});
```

Edit:  With some further searching here on StackOverflow, I have found this promising bit of code:

```
const mockUrlTree = router.parseUrl('/heroes/captain-marvel');
// @ts-ignore: force this private property value for testing.
router.currentUrlTree = mockUrlTree;
```

I get failures on this as well stating `.parseUrl` is not a function on router, despite being able to see it's right there in the class between `serializeUrl` and `isActive`.

Any suggestions on how to mock my path would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I've had the same doubt, maybe it will help someone else. Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296340/cannot-assign-to-var-because-it-is-a-read-only-property-in-angular-test-using), I've mock a readonly field with this:

```
const router: Router = TestBed.inject(Router);

Object.defineProperty(router, url, { value: '/your/path/here' });
Object.defineProperty(router, events, { value: myObservableHere }); // in my case
```